# What is {} with new object in java?

Tags: java

How do I refer `{}` in java. Is it a new object or class or datatype or something else?

I am going through some code in json to object conversion. It uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`. I would like to understand what is `{}`. Because methods always accepts object. When I do `new XXX()` then creation of object is done. So what is the need of extra `{}`?

```java
try {
  return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {});
} catch (IOException e) {
  LOGGER.error("Exception while de-serializing", e);
  return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an anonymous class expression:

```
return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {});
// -----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It creates a new instance of an anonymous class extending `TypeReference`. The `{}` is an empty class body. As Paul Lemarchand says in a comment, it's useful here because `TypeReference` is an `abstract` class (otherwise, you could just use `new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>()` without the `{}`). The body can be blank because although `TypeReference` is `abstract`, it doesn't have any `abstract` members; if it had `abstract` members, you'd have to define them within the class body of the anonymous class.

More in the [Java Anonymous Class Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) on Oracle's Java site.

Comment: Worth mentionning why it is useful there, that is because `TypeReference` is `abstract` as the other answer stated.

Answer (score 3):

It creates an anonymous class extending `TypeReference`. Because `TypeReference` is `abstract` thus you cannot instantiate it directly.